# std::unordered_map throws seg fault when inserting a specific key

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a python code base that sometimes invokes C++ programs to handle intensive workloads. One such code has to count all kmers of a certain size in a large text file. For each line it reads, it creates a temporary index that stores the position of each kmer. Here is the function that processes each line:

```
void process_read(char* read, int num) {
    int l = strlen(read) ;
    std::string seq(read) ;
    // index kmers
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> index ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= l - 1 - 15 ; i++) {
        std::string k = seq.substr(i, 15) ;
        if (global_index->find(k) == global_index->end()) {
            continue ;
        }
        if (index.find(k) == index.end()) {
            index.insert(std::make_pair(k, std::vector<int>(1, i))) ;
        } else {
            index[k].push_back(i) ;
        }
    }
    // 50+ lines of code commented out. It returns here
}
```

The code crashes every time it reaches a certain line of input:

```
ACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCAAACCATAACCCTAAACCTCACGATAACCCAAACCATCACCAAAAAAAAAAAAAACACACCTACCGAAACCAACAACATA
```

Out of the kmers in this line, only `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAC` and `CAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` make it to index. The code always crashes when trying to insert `CAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` for some reason I don't understand. I guess is a problem with these keys being inserted into the `unordered_map` in sequence. Changing the function to this will still result in the same crash when inserting the second key:

```
void process_read(char* read, int num) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> index ;
    index.insert(std::make_pair("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAC", std::vector<int>(1, 2))) ;
    index.insert(std::make_pair("CAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", std::vector<int>(1, 2))) ;
}
```

Now this function is clearly not accessing any global state unlike the original one so the problem has to be with these specific keys (notice that one is a circular shift of the other, the hash function used might not be comfortable with that); however, putting this code at the start of the program or writing another small program that only does this doesn't seem to reproduce the crash so I'm really confused.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Update: 
I get this stack trace during the crash. For reasons, I can't use gdb to debug so I guess this is the best I'm going to get. But don't know how to interpret it.

```
*** Error in `src/python/kmer/c_counter.out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000001eac690 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f189daa47e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82651)[0x7f189daaf651]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7f189dab1184]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_Znwm+0x18)[0x7f189e3a3e78]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x41c5e4]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x4146ea]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x41453a]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x41035b]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x40b3d8]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x40940a]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x404528]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x404f9d]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x405f42]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x4063d6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f189da4d830]
/src/python/kmer/c_counter.out[0x403b39]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00440000 r-xp 00000000 00:2f 546796                             src/python/kmer/c_counter.out
0063f000-00640000 rw-p 0003f000 00:2f 546796                             src/python/kmer/c_counter.out
014a0000-01ebf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f1898000000-7f1898021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f1898021000-7f189c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f189da2d000-7f189dbed000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1439150                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f189dbed000-7f189dded000 ---p 001c0000 fc:00 1439150                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f189dded000-7f189ddf1000 r--p 001c0000 fc:00 1439150                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f189ddf1000-7f189ddf3000 rw-p 001c4000 fc:00 1439150                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f189ddf3000-7f189ddf7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f189ddf7000-7f189de0d000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1439041                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f189de0d000-7f189e00c000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 1439041                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f189e00c000-7f189e00d000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 1439041                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f189e00d000-7f189e115000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1439141                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f189e115000-7f189e314000 ---p 00108000 fc:00 1439141                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f189e314000-7f189e315000 r--p 00107000 fc:00 1439141                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f189e315000-7f189e316000 rw-p 00108000 fc:00 1439141                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f189e316000-7f189e488000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 671990                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f189e488000-7f189e688000 ---p 00172000 fc:00 671990                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f189e688000-7f189e692000 r--p 00172000 fc:00 671990                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f189e692000-7f189e694000 rw-p 0017c000 fc:00 671990                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f189e694000-7f189e698000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f189e698000-7f189e6be000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1439146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f189e878000-7f189e89f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f189e8bc000-7f189e8bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f189e8bd000-7f189e8be000 r--p 00025000 fc:00 1439146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f189e8be000-7f189e8bf000 rw-p 00026000 fc:00 1439146                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f189e8bf000-7f189e8c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffea4907000-7ffea4929000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffea49b6000-7ffea49b9000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffea49b9000-7ffea49bb000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: *"so the problem has to be with these specific keys"* Not really --- if you are corrupting memory, a crash might appear to be in unexpected places.  It is *very* unlikely that your `std::unordered_map` has a bug for some keys. Please use a debugger or memory checker to see where things are going astray.

Comment: You don't really need that check `index.find(k) == index.end()` and the `insert` call. Just doing `index[k].push_back(i)` should work fine.

Comment: @Acorn you are suggesting something else in the program not included above is corrupting memory?

Comment: @DarthPaghius Possibly (I didn't check your code). I simply wanted to point out that crashes may or may not be related to the code you see at the crash point. It is a very strong indicator of memory corruption that, if you run the code independently, it does not crash.

Comment: @Acorn But everything here is local to the stack frame for the current invocation of this function. Doesn't seem like you can easily corrupt that.

Comment: you can speculate forever or just execute the code step by step in a debugger

Comment: By the way, why are you using `char*` for strings to begin with? If you're programming in C++ use C++ streams for input and read strings into `std::string`. That will also be one less source of memory corruption problems (perhaps you read a string into a to small buffer?).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using C file I/O because it's faster than C++. Those `char*` are converted to a string then.

Comment: @DarthPaghius Whether the variables are only "local" does not matter. If you have corrupted your memory, symptoms vary wildly depending on what was corrupted, how the code was laid out, etc. It may crash thousands of instructions later from the actual start of the problem. Again, use a memory checker or a debugger, it should be very easy to fix unless you have special constraints.

Comment: That sounds like a premature optimization. Anyway, without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be really hard to help you anyway. Also consider using memory debugger tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or similar.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was hoping for some suggestions while I'm trying to figure out how to use a memory debugger.

Comment: It may be worth a *null pointer* check for `char* read`. Also you don't need to use `std::strlen` you can get the length of the string from the string `seq.size()`. That will save you iterating the whole string twice.

Comment: As has been highlighted earlier, this looks like memory corruption.  Try running your simple version from a main which only calls process_read.  It won't crash

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Dude... don't EVER use `char*` without knowing what you're doing. I mean, this is way worse than `const char*` and I'm sure your compiler is bloating you with warnings... and way way worse than `std::string`! Why not pass an `std::string` by reference? The conversion from `char*` to `std::string` has a gazillion security holes that it should never be done the way you're doing it here! To safely convert from `char*` to `std::string` you should at least ensure that the length of your string is sane. I bet if you throw away all `char*` and replace them with `std::string`, it'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

> Changing the function to this will still result in the same crash when inserting the second key:
>
> [...]
>
> putting this code at the start of the program or writing another small program that only does this doesn't seem to reproduce the crash so I'm really confused.

`std::unordered_map` has no relevant global state that could change between "everything is fine if I run this test function at the start" and "if I run this test function later, the map crashes". You have memory corruption due to undefined behavior somewhere else in your program - the observations you made are the strongest proof you could get for that.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature suggests that you don't necessarily have a null ended string(one that has a \0 as the last character).

But you don't treat it as such(you should use variants that take num as a parameter). I suspect this pattern repeats in other places and at some point you corrupt your memory.

If I were you i would build the binary with Valgrind or some other memory analysis tool and run it again. It will catch the incorrect access where it happens.

The way you use unordered_map looks fine to me.

Comment: But I'm converting it to a string and work with that. And even that string is read-only. The substring are new strings copied from it. Also note that both the keys here have the length of 15 which is the intended value and the for loop's bounds checking assures we don't overshoot the string.

Comment: @DarthPaghius Please stop trying to explain what you think is (or isn't) the problem; and listen to the suggestions that 3 people have already given you.

Comment: @DarthPaghius If your input string is not *null terminated* then you are not converting it to a string correctly or safely. Is that the case? Is your input *null terminated*?

Comment: @darthpaghius that's the problem with memory corruption, it doesn't always crash where you make the mistake. It can run fine for a while and then crash is what looks like innocent code. That's why i suggest Valgrind, because it catches the original error. The string handling is just a suspicion based on the code I've seen. The original mistake can be a number of things(off by one mistake or indexing the wrong pointer or any other number of ways to corrupt the memory).

Comment: @Sorin I don't have access to a memory debugger on the development system so I can't check that yet. But that's going to be the first thing I try when I can get my hands on a debugger.